# How to pass contact id and contact lookup fields in to visual force page?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I want auto populate contact and account fields when ever we create Opportunity record from contacts related list. But  below was not giving as expected results...please anyone make correct.

PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/OppVfPage?CF00N40000002fEB2={**!Contact.Name**}&CF00N40000002fEB2_lkid={!**Contact.Id**}&conid={!**Contact.Id**}');

after page opens the contact or account fields were not populated and the URL displays like...

https://c.cs15.visual.force.com/apex/OppVfPage?CF00N40000002fEB2=%7B%21**Contact.Name**%7D%3FCF00N40000002fEB2_lkid%3D%7B%21**Contact.Id**%7D%3Fconid%3D%7B%21**Contact.Id**%7D

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create PageReference - and its constructor accepts String.
But String is not a Formula, merge fields will not be populated.
You must either format string properly or set parameters:

```
PageReference yourPage = Page.YourPage;
yourPage.getParameters().put('Id', contact.Id);
return yourPage;
```

OR

```
PageReference yourPage = new PageReference('/apex/YporPage?Id=' + contact.Id); 
return yourPage;
```

Comment: I am forwarding conId in to Opportunity page....when ever i create a new opportunity from contact related list then i want to auto populate contact and account. but from above it doesn't work

Comment: It is just example of how set paramethers in URL from code. There is some post about URL hack SF : http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/